# How can i show the values of my database in my html page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to show the value of a columns from my database in my html page

Right now I have the connection and the echo value is showing

But I want it to show it in my html, how can I fix that?

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT 8krt, 14krt, 18krt FROM orders';

mysql_select_db('my_database');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    echo "First14 : {$row['14krt']}  <br> ".
         "Second18 : :" . $row["18krt"] . "  <br> ";
} 

mysql_close($conn);
?>

 <div class="divWrapper">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblForm">
            <tr>
                <td>HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE VALUE OF "14krt" from the database</td>
             <td>HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE VALUE OF "18krt" from the database</td>
           </tr>

            <div>
```

Comment: I tried this :  <td><?php echo = . $row["18krt"] . ?></td> but no results

Comment: You can also `<td><?php echo $row['18krt']; ?></td>`

Comment: `<td><?php $row['18krt']; ?></td>` at least I remember it that way

Comment: You're not echo'ing anything. You're just stating `$variable`, that's it. You need to do `echo`

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope problem. Make `$value` a global var like below:

```
    $value;   
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
        {
            $value = $row['14krt'];
        } 

    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
```

if `$row['14krt']` come more than once then use array.

```
$value=array();   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
   $value[] = $row['14krt'];
} 

<?php for($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++) { ?>
<td><?php echo $value[$i] ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This is the best way/option! Thank you very much! I want to vote for you but i can't .. May god bless ya

Comment: This is only for 1 result though. This makes the while loop redundant.

Comment: not actually, op wants while loop for more than one value.

Comment: This will overlap the variable `$value` the whole time? So it only consists the last row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT 8krt, 14krt, 18krt FROM orders';

    mysql_select_db('my_database');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    ?>
    <div class="divWrapper">
        <?php
if (mysql_num_rows($retval)) {  ?>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblForm">
            <?php

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
   { ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['14krt'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['18krt'];?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
   }
   echo "</table>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `while` around the TDs as well:

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
   <td><?php $row['14krt'] ?></td>
   <td><?php $row["18krt"] ?></td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using while / endwhile inside the table element

```
<div class="divWrapper">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblForm">
<? while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['14krt']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['14krt']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<? endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you've missed your end table tag